# How to sum and sort a column of a tab file that contain comma data with Awk

Tags: awk

I have a tab file like this, final_score.csv:

```
fufu  -2  map1,map3,map8
fifi  6   map5,map1
fofo  0   map4
lili  -9  map8,map1
```

And I want to create an other tab file like that:

```
map8  -11
map1  -5
map3  -2
map4  0
map5  6
```

So I need to list all my compound and sum those who as more then one hit and sort them increasingly.
So far I've got:

```
awk -F"\t" '{
  split($3,a,",");
  for(i=1; i in a; i++){
    print a[i],"\t",$2;
  }
}' final_score.csv > bla.csv

awk -F"\t" '$1 {sum+=$2} END {print $1,"\t",sum}' bla.csv
```

But it gave me just :

```
map1  -11
```

I only have the last "map" in the file and the sum of the number column, how can I solve that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Concise, testable sample input, expected output, clear requirements, the code you tried yourself, the actual output, etc. - a breath of fresh air. Thanks for posting a such a well-formed question!

Answer (score 2):

`awk` + `sort` solution:

```
awk '{ len=split($3, a, ","); for(i=1;i<=len;i++) b[a[i]] += $2; delete a }
      END{ for(i in b) print i, b[i] }' yourfile | sort -k2
```

The output:

```
map8 -11
map3 -2
map1 -5
map4 0
map5 6
```

Comment: I Roman, thanks for your response! It's seems to work, but with my true dataset the "k2" sort seems to not be the good one, it trigger with negative value such as : 5 , 1 , 0 , -1 , -11, -12, -2, -22 , etc .. Do you have the right "-sort" for that type of integer please ? :)

Comment: @mstatam, try to add numeric sorting `-k2n`

Comment: Awesome ! ty very much

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk version that does the output sorting directly:

```
$ gawk '{ split($3, a, ","); for (i in a) b[a[i]] += $2 }
        END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"; OFS="\t";
              for (i in b) print i, b[i] }' final_score.tsv
map8    -11
map1    -5
map3    -2
map4    0
map5    6
```